# Binding a text containing javascript to innerHTML in a template

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime

For a metro style app, in Windows 8, I have a list of article that i pass to a flip View Control. Each Article have a description text in HTML which contains javascript. I know we have to use this function to load unsafe content to innerHTML :

```
 var someElement = document.getElementById('someElementID');
 MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(
 function() { someElement.innerHTML = '<div onclick="console.log(\"hi\");">hi</div>' }
 );
```

But how can i achieve that when my innerHTML property is within a template?

here is my template  :

```
 <div id="ItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
 <div class="itemDetail fragment">
   <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
 <!--       <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>-->
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle"></span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <article>
            <img class="article-image" src="#" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" data-win-bind="src:  urlImage; alt: title" />
            <div class="item-content" data-win-bind="innerHTML: description"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
     </div>
  </div>
```

for this flipVIew :

```
  <div id="basicFlipView" 
data-win-control="WinJS.UI.FlipView"
      data-win-options="{itemTemplate:select('#ItemTemplate')}">
 </div>
```

and here is how i Fill it :

```
        var dataControl = document.getElementById("basicFlipView").winControl;
        dataControl.itemDataSource = dataList.dataSource;
        dataControl.currentPage = myState.index;
```

Thank you very much for your help

EDIT : As Dominic Hopton suggested I used a WinJS.Binding.initializer. This is a quite complex way of doing a binding. I've done this but it doesn't work properly. Do you see something wrong :

```
 var toUnsafeHTML = WinJS.Binding.initializer(
     function toUnsafeHTML(source, sourceProperty, dest, destProperty) {


     function setUnsafeHTML() {
         MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(
         function () { dest.innerHTML = source.innerHTML }
         );
     }

     return WinJS.Binding.bind(source, {
         innerHTML : setUnsafeHTML}
     );

 }
 );

//
// Binding initializers have to be public, so publish this out
// via a namespace
//
WinJS.Namespace.define("TemplateControl", {
    toUnsafeHTML: toUnsafeHTML
});
```

and in the html :

```
 <div id="ItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
 <div class="itemDetail fragment">
   <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
 <!--       <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>-->
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle"></span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <article>
            <img class="article-image" src="#" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" data-win-bind="src:  urlImage; alt: title" />
            <div class="item-content" data-win-bind="innerHTML: TemplateControl.toUnsafeHTML"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
     </div>
  </div>
```

It never enter the setUnsafeHTML function...

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is even possible using databinding, at least not using any of several techniques I tested.

That being said...even if you COULD do this...if the articles you are loading are coming from the Internet, this would be a VERY bad idea.

If you load script from the network, you expose yourself to the possibility that it contains malicious code. There's a reason this limitation exists, which is to protect you (and more importantly, those who use your app) from potential exploits.

If you haven't already, please read the docs for execUnsafeLocalFunction, as they detail why attempting to inject script from the web in the local app context is a bad idea:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767331.aspx

See also (the section titled "Dynamically adding HTML"):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx

and:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx

which lists the tags, attributes, and CSS properties that are considered safe or unsafe.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you do decide to do this, you can build a WinJS Binding initializer that will allow you to do more than just transfer the value - e.g. Wrap in the execUnsafeLocalFunction.

Comment: Thank you. @Dominic Hopton, I'm trying to build a converter which would execute the execUnsafeLocalFunction when the binding is called. But I don't succeed in getting the innerHTML element from my template. Do you have any example of the wraping you are talking about? Thank you

Comment: The converter won't help you - it doesn't give you access to your destination element, only a value conversion. You'll need to write an actual binding initializer. This doesn't Appear to be well documented. But there's a sample here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DeclarativeBinding-bfcb42a5/sourcecode?fileId=43658&pathId=134403190 you need the toCSSColor function to start from. Where dest, wrap in exec unsafe, and set inner HTML. be aware of security ickyness if you do this.

Comment: This example is extremely complex...I tried to adapt it to my case because I really think that it is what I need. It still doesn't work (I edited my question at the top) but I'm on the right way.